# How to Archive Storage tables?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have a scenario, where daily a storage table will be created with current date.e.g. Table412019 . So after some interval i need to archive the tables , i.e. in each month i need to archive all the table or need to merge all tables into a single table named Jan2019( which will contain all table rows Table112019 to Table1312019).

What is the best way to do it. All are in the Azure Table storage account.

Comment: What's the purpose of the archive? Are you looking for a way to archive in a cheaper manner? What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck? Give us some more (relevant) info/code so we can help. Please refer to [ask] and try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: You are right, we are trying to store the data for future analysis in cheaper manner.

Where as i thought of Azure table copy option , or ADF . I haven't tried anything hand on. So there is no way that i can put some code

Comment: I am not looking for a exact code to do it, rather i am looking for the approach that i can avail which is available & cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

The Hot, Cool, and Archive storage tiers are *only* available for **Blob Storage** (Source: [Azure Blob storage: Premium (preview), Hot, Cool, and Archive storage tiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers)).

Since you're talking about Table Storage, migrating the data to an 'archive' will not help with the costs.

Moving the data into 'just' another table within the same storage account should be easy enough. You can, for instance, use [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-table-storage) or [AZCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy).

Comment: So can i use data factory to merge multiple storage table (form 1st jan to 31st jan tables) into a single table(assume Jan2019Table)?

Comment: I tried AzCopy its working, but we need to transfer the table data to a blob then from there .manifest file will be helpful to restore into the single table storage. But its manual.. need to think of doing it in Powershell to Automate.  If Azcopy is there in Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge multiple tables into one single table, I hope my way could help you.I used logic app to implement it.

These two tables are prepared for merging.
[image][image]

**After merging it would be like this:**
[image]

And here is my Logic app flow:
Firstly get Entities from table and table2:
[image]
[image]

Secondly choose action "Insert or Merge Entity":
[image]

After these save it and Run Trigger.If you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: Although this is a nice approach, this will be feasible when we have less number of tables , but in my case the table count will vary according to the days count/month..

Comment: @Titi， per my understanding, you better change the way you store data. You could store your data with a "time" property in months. Because no matter which way you choose, as time goes on, your table count will be huge, even there is a service could merge multiple tables mechanically , there will still be a timeout problem.

Comment: Thought of doing it, but scenario is different, as per day the record count may exceed more then 10-20 lacs so single table is a good option so at least we can open the table , otherwise for huge data it crashes sometime ..

Comment: @Titi，you mean you store data in moths, and store more than 10-20 entities everyday, then you table will crash? How could that be? The max size of table scale target is huge.

Comment: @Titi And when your table is huge, what do you mean "crash"? Could you check table with "Azure Storage Explorer" tool?

Comment: When i say crash, i.e. when we are trying to download or view the huge data, the Storage explored Crashes while retrieving that much data. So although we are storing a huge data we are unable to view it.